# IP in client's request (iOS, AFNetworking) unchanged on DNS swap (AWS ELB)

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, dns, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

Our servers are hosted on AWS and we are using a setup which swaps the DNS between two ELBs (for two different server setups).

We have verified that the DNS change propagates quickly (~30 seconds) using curl from a local terminal - it does not seem to happen when generating requests from our iOS app. Given that the app was started before the swap - the app continues to communicate with the old ELB, regardless of the change.

Our iOS app sends periodic server calls (every 5 seconds), and when the servers are killed, the app starts communicating with the new server after a period of about one minute.

This happens with both AFNetworking 2.0 (`AFHTTPSessionManager`) and AFNetworking 1.3 (`AFHTTPClient`).

We would like to know if there is a good built-in mechanism on either ends to make the app connect to the new server. A solution on the server side is preferable - because we want upcoming changes to be supported by the app currently in the AppStore.